# Highlighted UIButton when is pressed won't highlight the first time is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have look around to highlight a button when is pressed and I came up with this..

```
//The button #1
-(IBAction)Number1:(UIButton *)sender{
    [self buttonPressed:sender];
    [self appendDigit:@"1"];
}

//The function for buttonPressed
- (void) buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

    [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ButtonPressed.png"] forState:(UIControlStateHighlighted)];
}
```

It highlights the button exactly how I want but only after the second time is pressed. Not sure why is doing this, but it is.. So, I'm wondering what am I missing here?

I have seen other posts which approach this in a different way but I fond that it was a bit different on how I implemented my calculator..

Well, I hope you guys can give a hand or guide in the right direction.. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is this line of code

```
[sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ButtonPressed.png"] forState:(UIControlStateHighlighted)];
```

is NOT yet processed during the first tap.

You will have to make an IBOutlet of that button like

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
```

Then in **viewDidLoad**

```
    [self.button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ButtonPressed.png"] forState:(UIControlStateHighlighted)];
```

**Sample Project in Github:** 
https://github.com/voyage11/HighLightBtn

Comment: I'm guessing, I have to connect that IBOutlet to my buttons in my calculator, right?

Comment: Yes, the same button that you use -(IBAction)Number1:(UIButton *)sender

Comment: only one connection can be handle by the IBOutlet? Because works fine for just 1 button, but when I connect the rest to that Outlet nothing works.. :(

Comment: You must be doing something wrong, double check everything. I have uploaded a github project above for your reference.

Comment: I mean, it works but just for 1 button.. the rest of the buttons they won't work if I try to connect them to the same IBOutlet button..

Comment: Each button should have only 1 IBOutlet, if you have 10 buttons, you should have 10 IBOutlet. Then each button also has to setBackgroundImage in viewDidLoad.

Comment: That's what I meant before. Is there a way to make within a function or something to not have that much of repetitive code?

Comment: For IBOutlet, it is the only way. For IBAction, yes, you can connect to the same method. But make sure that you know what you are doing. I would like to suggest you to master the basic in xCode first before trying to experiment new things.

Comment: Check the latest code on Github, I added a new button to the same IBAction and it shows you how to handle 2 buttons in the same function. If my answer satisfy your question, please accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the background image only *after* the button has been clicked once. Instead, move your "pressed" code into viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear. In other words, this code:

```
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ButtonPressed.png"] forState:(UIControlStateHighlighted)];
```

Here `button` should refer to your button, as in an IBOutlet.

Here's why: this line code doesn't mean "set the background to ButtonPressed.png this very moment." Instead, it means: "when this button's state changes to highlighted, the background should be ButtonPressed.png." As such, you need to run this line just *once* (not every time the button is pressed), and *before* the button gets pressed.

Comment: got a question, only one button can be connected to the IBOutlet? because, it's the only way that is working in the proper way.. I tried to connect the other buttons to that outlet and it won't work..